# Code Behind of button background converter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, valueconverter

I have a `Grid` which is dynamically divided into cells and filled with buttons (in loops). Each `Button` has a `Content` which is a number. I want to dynamically change the button background. For example, all the buttons which content is one are red, others blue, then switch the variable to two, and all the buttons which content is two are red and others are blue etc. I wrote such a converter

```
public class RadioBtnToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;
        switch (input)
        {
            case "1":
                return Brushes.Red;
            default:
                return Brushes.SlateBlue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is for case where buttons content is equal to 1, I want to make it switchable, what is more, i don't know how to bind the background color with converter. any tips?

EDIT:
Dynamically changing background solved, now it's just about making the converter switchable with radio buttons

Comment: Okey, I assume i should make value converter class which store for me a button right? because I make normal button Object

Comment: everything is creating dynamically, this task does not really connect to the XAML. Anyway i solved dynamically changing the background, now it's just about to make this converter switchable :)

Comment: You answered your question yourself. Yes you can make a converter for setting the background value of button.